# Хочу сделать ошибку 429 Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Как можно сделать чтобы, когда шло серверу слишком много запросов от одного клиента, то он бы отвечал 429?

Comment: я бы поставил `nginx` перед `express` и настроил бы limit_conn

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limit-redis